# Pandastable how to show a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Heyaa, got a work around but I'm wondering if there is a direct way to display a pandas data frame directly in a pandastable instead of exporting it to a CSV and then importing the CSV.

Thanks for the help
Torolito

My workaround code:

```
    def show testdata:
        dTestData = TestDataCheck
        dTestData.to_csv('TD_Temp.csv', index = False)
        dTDa1 = tkinter.Toplevel()
        dTDa1.title('TestData')
        dTDaPT = pt.Table(dTDa1, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True )
        dTDaPT.importCSV('TD_Temp.csv')
        dTDaPT.show()
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit further what it is you're trying to accomplish? Are you trying to display your pandas dataframe in a GUI?

Comment: more or less
I'm coding a tkinter gui

for doing some data analysis with a really crappy source.
(constantly changing)

For having a look how the dataframe looks like, I would like to use pandastable (DataExplorer) in a popup window. It looks excel like, kind of familiar and I see really quickly if something is wrong.

TestDataCheck is alreada a pandas dataframe

Comment: I would like to define TestDataCheck directly for pantastable (pt) but can't find the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the dataframe directly in the constructor:

`dTDaPT = pt.Table(dTDa1, dataframe=dTestData, showtoolbar=True, showstatusbar=True)`